# How to remove ScrollBar and indent line of scroll

Tags: css, web

How to remove Scrollbar but don't remove scroll line and how to indent this line?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: none; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); 
    background-color: #ff8000;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by scroll line ? scroll track?

Comment: @karthick Jun scrollbar thumb